# Can't Install  11.10 desktop 64-bit

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, installation

I am trying to install  11.10 desktop 64bit on a brand new ssd with no existing operating system.  I downloaded it from the Ubuntu site, I used Roxio to burn image to cd, and booted from the cd.

I don't get the option to install or try.  Instead all I get is an error `not a com 32r image` with a boot prompt.  This message repeats.  I tried typing `help` at this prompt.  A help menu displays, but then it freezes and I am unable to press any of the F2 to F12 keys.

I tried typing `live` at the prompt and it just sets there.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having problems with the 64-bit version, try the 32-bit.

[you can find it here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)

if you can you may want to try to use a USB instead of a CD since you can format a USB, you have as many tries as you want.

Comment: thank you everyone for all the great help.  i ended up re-downloading and then using the usb installation instead of cd.  problem is now solved.

how do i mark this post/question as solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve the problem as suggested here..

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1737637

It is likely to be a bad download or a poor burn - please check by doing a ISO check as per the community wiki:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: unfortunately, i have already tried typing "help" and this solution didn't work for me.  after typing "help", i get the help menu and then it freezes.  i am unable to press any options or exit the help screen.  from that point, i have to hard reset the laptop.